# DELETE request affects a next request of any type in Safari

Tags: ajax, safari, jqxhr

There is a strange issue in my app, which takes place only in Safari browser.

After a DELETE request has been completed with 204 success status, the folowing request (it may be PUT, GET, any type) also got 204 status as response instead of 200 expected. All next requests are all right, just the first request after DELETE has a trouble.

Note that this situation doesn't appears in any other browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was found. There was no Safari strange behaviour. The problem was in requests cashing.